# PostgreSQL Calendar Days function

Tags: postgresql

My requirement is change week days to calendar days from below query.

```
AVG(if(is_emergency is null or is_emergency = 0 , week_days_elapsed_excluding_holidays(c.mailed::date,c.date_received,'NE'),null)) as   AVERAGE_TAT_Standard_days, 
AVG(if(is_emergency = 1, week_days_elapsed_excluding_holidays(c.mailed::date,c.date_received,'NE'),null))  as  AVERAGE_TAT_Urgent_days
```

Comment: Looks to me like `week_days_elapsed_excluding_holidays` is a custom function, you may need to locate the code from that function. I would want to see the whole query, some sample data and and expected result to help more

Comment: Got it Thank you,